# Convert numbers with different length to dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to convert NUMBERS like (9012020, 12012020) to dates (20201201, 20200901),

I have different lengths of this numeric values like what you see above I tried

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(col_name), 'YYYYMMDD')
from table_name
```

I need your help please thanks

Comment: Apply a format in TO_CHAR adding leading zeroes (or LPAD) and use a matching format 'MMDDYYYY' in TO_DATE

Comment: can I flip the date to be like YYYYMMDD ?

Comment: A date can't be flipped, it's stored in an internal format. TO_DATE is simply used to cast a string representing a date to a DATE using a given format and TO_CHAR vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those values are **valid** date values, i.e. there's no something like

- ab232020
- 38269283

and all values follow the same format, then you could do the following:

(altering the session just that you'd know what represents what; you don't have to do that)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Query itself:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select  9012020 from dual union all
  3     select 12012020 from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         to_date(lpad(col, 8, '0'), 'mmddyyyy') result
  7  from test;

       COL RESULT
---------- ----------
   9012020 01.09.2020
  12012020 01.12.2020

SQL>
```